# Scraping Multiple Pages Using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I made this web scraper that takes data from a page on Home Depot's website. I am new to web scraping as a whole was just curious if there was a way that I could code this to keep clicking the next page button and scraping the respective data points from each page until it reaches the end? Here is the link I am using: https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv'
path = '/Users/Office/Documents/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)
skus = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-identifier--bd1f5')))
prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-format__main-price')))

prod_num = []
prod_price = []

for sku in skus:
    prod_num.append(sku.text)

for price in prices:
    prod_price.append(price.text)

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price})
df.to_csv('HD_test.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: what is the issue? selenium can just click next page and proceed parsing.

Comment: I added this chunk and am getting error:page = driver.find_elements_by_name('hd-pagination__link ')
next_page = page.click()

while next_page is True:

    for sku in skus:
        prod_num.append(sku.text)

    for price in prices:
        prod_price.append(price.text)

Comment: I think it is just some logic. Open selenium in UI mode and run debugger and see when it breaks. I use selenium for a multi page story which works nicely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my loop for pagination not working in python selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75795768/why-is-my-loop-for-pagination-not-working-in-python-selenium)