# Why is my loop for pagination not working in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I successfully coded a web scrape off a home depot that just does one page at a time below. When I go to add a loop to go through multiple pages it seems to break.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv'
path = '/Users/Office/Documents/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)


skus = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-identifier--bd1f5')))
prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-format__main-price')))

prod_num = []
prod_price = []

for sku in skus:
    prod_num.append(sku.text)

for price in prices:
    prod_price.append(price.text)

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price})
df.to_csv('HD_test.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Here is my code with the pagination loop. it seems to be giving me errors but i cannot seem to figuree out why, the logic seems to make sense to me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv'
path = '/Users/Office/Documents/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)


skus = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-identifier--bd1f5')))
prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-format__main-price')))

prod_num = []
prod_price = []

for i in range(72):
    for sku in skus:
        prod_num.append(sku.text)

    for price in prices:
        prod_price.append(price.text)

    next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('://a[aria- label="Next"]')
    next_page.click()

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price})
df.to_csv('HD_test.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I tried different methods(xpath,css selector, etc.) to find the Next button to click but it doesn't work. Anyway, I found another way around to solve your problem regarding pagination.

Here is the complete solution,

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def scrape_page_data():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'results-wrapped')))
    container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'results-wrapped')

    # scroll down to load all content on the page
    for _ in range(4):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
        time.sleep(2)

    skus = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-identifier--bd1f5')
    prices = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-format__main-price')

    return skus, prices


def pagination(url, pages=1):
    prod_num = []
    prod_price = []

    page_num = 0
    # iterate over the pages
    for i in range(1, pages+1):

        #print(f"this is page {i}")
        driver.get(f"{url}?Nao={page_num}")
        skus, prices = scrape_page_data()

        for sku in skus:
            prod_num.append(sku.text)
        for price in prices:
            prod_price.append(price.text)

        # increment it by 24 since each page has 24 data
        page_num += 24
        time.sleep(1)

    return prod_num, prod_price


website = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
prod_num, prod_price = pagination(website, pages=3)

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price})
df.to_csv('HD_test.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

output:

```
code                               price
Model# 2695-10CX                   $64900
Model# 3697-22                     $39900
Model# 2767-20                     $27900
Model# 2892-22CT                   $19900
Model# 2695-27S                    $49900
      ...                           ...
Model# 2475-21CP                   $12900
Model# 2867-20                     $83900
Model# 2529-20                     $24900
Model# 2767-22R                    $49900
Model# 2854-20-2854-20-48-11-1862  $40900
```

here, we passed pages=3, which basically means we want to get the first 3 pages, and per page, we get 24 data points. So, in total, we get all 72 data from all the 3 pages.

similarly, we can get the first 2 pages by passing the "pages=2" and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have access to the page. But the problem I can see from the code is that you are searching skus and prices outside of the loop of the pages. When you cliuck in next_page the DOM probably regenerate your elements and acting on them will not work.

You have to make sure that after every change in the DOM (for example clicking an element that produces a visible change) you are finding again that elements that where regenerated.

That may be something like:

```py
prod_num = []
prod_price = []

for i in range(72):
    skus = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-identifier--bd1f5')))
    prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-format__main-price')))
    for sku in skus:
        prod_num.append(sku.text)

    for price in prices:
        prod_price.append(price.text)

    next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('://a[aria- label="Next"]')
    next_page.click()
```